# Display labels and moving shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

I am new to C# and WPF. I want to do the following :

1. Display few labels one after the other after exactly 5 seconds,
2. After finishing the above I have to move a shape on the canvas for about ten times with time gap of 5 seconds between each move,
3. Do the above but with time gap of just 2 seconds.

Here is the code :

```
    DispatcherTimer timer2 = new DispatcherTimer();
    float timerTime = 10;
    Label timerlabel = new Label();

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbl.Content = "test";
        startDisplay("hello!!");
        startDisplay("bye");
        Shapemove(1);
    }

    private void startDisplay(string st)
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        timer.Start();
        timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            lbl.Content = st;
        };
    }

    private void Shapemove(int i)
    {

        timer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);
        timer2.Start();

    }

    void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        if (timerTime > 0)
        {
            canvas1.Children.Remove(timerlabel);
            timerTime--;

            canvas1.Children.Add(timerlabel);
            timerlabel.FontSize = 20;
            timerlabel.Content = timerTime + "s";
            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle1, rand.Next(640));
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle1, rand.Next(480));
        }
        else
        {
            timer2.Stop();
        }
    }
```

But problem with above is :

1. Both timer and timer2 set off at same time.
2. The labels are not displayed one after other  - test appears and 5 seconds later bye appears, hello never appears!!
3. Is there a way to reset the timer and call them as function repeatedly like for Shapemove or startDisplay function mentioned above?

Kindly help me solve the above issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a timer. Use StoryBoards instead.

In a Storyboard you can arrange Animations that manipulate Visibility, Opacity, Location, ... any (dependency)property of the controls.

[See Animations in this tutorial](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1028-wpf-tutorial-styles-triggers-and-animations-7.aspx)